# bookshelfjs node relationship

Tags: mysql, node.js, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I have a models for both `User` and `UserRole`.  There are currently two roles and many users across those two roles.  I can't find a way to get to the *role* data on a fetch for *user*.

The error that I'm seeing is: `Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'user_roles.user_id' in 'where clause'`.

```
var User = bookshelf.Model.extend({ 
    tableName: 'users',
    role: function() {
        return this.hasOne(UserRole);
    }
}, {
    lookupByToken: Promise.method(function(token) {
        if (!token) throw new Error('Token is required');
        return new this({token: token}).fetch({require: true, withRelated:['role']});
    })
});
```

.

```
var UserRole = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'user_roles',
  users: function() {
    return this.belongsToMany(User, 'users', 'role_id', 'id');
  }
});

module.exports = UserRole;
```

The knex migration looks as follows:

```
knex.schema.createTable('user_roles', function (table) {
    table.increments();
    table.string('role').notNullable();
    table.timestamps();
}).table('users', function(table) {
    table.integer('role_id').unsigned().references('user_roles.id');
})
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The `User` model was incorrect and should have read:

```
role: function() {
    return this.belongsTo(UserRole, 'id');
}
```

Using `user.role()` now works as expected with that change.